# Cocoa binding to a particular item in an array controller

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, key-value-coding

Is it possible using `NSArrayController` to bind a `NSTextField`'s value to a particular item in the array?  In particular, I want to bind to a property on the first item in the array, and show nothing if the array is empty.

Using `arrangedObjects.command` shows just "(" -- presumably it's trying to show a multi-line string with comma-separated strings for each item.  I just want the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind the text field to `selection.command`, and programmatically set the array controller's selection index to 0. You may need to also re-set the selection index to 0 any time you add or remove items to the content array.

Obviously, this won't work if you're allowing the user to select items within the array controller (you'd need a second array controller). I'm assuming that's not the case, since if it were, I'd expect you to want to show the user-selected object, instead of always the first object.

EDIT: Better yet, do nothing like this—if the object that is first in the array has some special status, you should make a separate non-array property (in the same object that holds the original array, from which I assume the array controller is getting it) to hold the object that has that status.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the selection property.  Thank you -- that should work. (And you're right, this array is never user-editable).